# secure and efficient file uploader

Tags: php, python, django, upload

I am looking for a decent file uploader. I'm using django, but while i don't NEED a django file uploader, python is preferable. php would also be fine.

can anyone point me in the direction of a good file uploader which is secure and efficient?

**EDIT**: I need the server-side handler of file uploads.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Agree with jeerose: **Uploadify is a nice app.**

I've made a simple Django wrapper for it as well if you're interested:  [django-uploadify](http://wiki.github.com/tstone/django-uploadify).  It basically gives you a template tag which renders uploadify and fires a Django signal whenever a file is received.

How you implement the 'handler' you mentioned above is simply a matter of subscribing to the signal and then doing whatever you wish with the incoming data. (the wiki includes an example of creating a new File Model if that's the kind of thing you're looking for)

Comment: i think i can tweak this. i was pretty certain that i posted a comment here about my users possibly not having flash, but even so i should be able to play around with django-uploadify. the users without flash will just have to get flash. it's nice when you have that kind of power at work... ; )

Answer (score 2):

I'm using [uploadify](http://www.uploadify.com/) which is an upload plugin for jQuery with a flash progress bar. I use some basic php for the upload script.  It can be made as secure as you need with a little investigating the forum.

Comment: i think i should have specified i'm looking for the handler. i'm not as concerned with the ui as i am with the actual server side handling of the upload. is your php script open source?

Comment: I actually just modified the handler that came with Uploadify.  If you download it and check out their demo php upload script you might have some success.  If you need image upload/resizing or file upload ideas let me know.